# Is it possible to set max-height for a row in google chart table?

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization

I want to set a max-height property to a row in a google-charts (table) 
and set overflow-text : ellipsis.
Is that possible ?

Comment: yes, use config option --> `cssClassNames.tableRow`

Comment: doesnt work....

Comment: will you please share the code?